# Проверка на палиндром

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Делал задание на проверку палиндром строка или нет. В интернет смотрел и код у всех очень большой и не очень понятен мне. Я сделал сам и получилось как-то очень мало кода. Может я сделал что-то не то? Вроде ж работает и проверяет. Подскажите.

```
$str = "A nut for a jar of tuna";
$str = strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$str));

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
    $left .= $str[$i];
    $right = $str[$i].$right;
}
if($left == $right){
    echo "$str - это Палиндром";
}else{
    echo "$str - Это не Палиндром";
}
```

Comment: Какова [асимптотика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/«O»_большое_и_«o»_малое) такого решения?

Comment: да нормально на встроенных функциях.... можно даже меньше http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/854565c3a0dc615bc8192de729eed87315cabe57

Comment: Правда на русских буквах не прокатит

Comment: 5 минут назад сделал, про это не подумал

Comment: `strrev($str) === $str` не пойдёт?

Comment: Уже переделал на лучше вариант. Сравнение по символьно с начала и конца. (так быстрее)

Answer (score 2):

В целом подход верный, но вот цикл

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
  $left .= $str[$i];
  $right = $str[$i].$right;
}
```

можно заменить на метод **strrev** который переворачивает строку 
вот дока: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strrev.php
Но если интересует нативный подход, то для проверки слова на палиндром достаточно знать, что одна половина строки равна другой И псевдо код примерно будет выглядить так

```
function isPalindrome (text)
  if text is null
    return false
  left ← 0
  right ← text.length - 1
  while (left < right)
    if text[left] is not text[right]
      return false
    left ← left + 1
    right ← right - 1
 return true
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов *(работает так же и с кириллицей)* :

```
echo palindrome('А роза упала на лапу Азора'); // "Палиндромная строка"

function palindrome($str) {
    $str = str_replace(' ', '', mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8'));
    $rev = join(array_reverse(preg_split('||u', $str)));
    return $str == $rev ? 'Палиндромная строка' : 'Простая строка';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

С удивлением обнаружил, что в php нет нативной `mb_strrev`..

```
function mb_strrev($str){
    preg_match_all('/./u', $str, $ar);
    return implode('', array_reverse($ar[0]));
}

$str = 'А роза упала на лапу Азора';
$str = mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $str));
var_dump(mb_strrev($str) === $str); // true
```