# Как поправить кодировку?

Tags: php

Делаю проверку на палиндром, но с русскими символами, что то не так. Почему кодировка кривая?
Кто то подскажет ?

```html
$text = strtolower("апрпа");
$text = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9]/","", $text);
function isPalindrom($text)
{
    $halfLen = floor(strlen($text)/2);
    $len = strlen($text)-1;

    for($i = 0; $i < $halfLen; $i++){
        if($text[$i] != $text[$len - $i]){
            return "$text - Not Palindrom!";
        }
    }
    return "$text - is Palindrom!";
}
echo isPalindrom($text);
```

Comment: А, в какой кодировки приходят данные? У Вас идёт преобразование кодировки. Вы уверены, что оно необходимо?

Comment: аб�бааб�ба Вот так

Comment: @Andrii для кириллицы есть вариант [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745278/185343)

Comment: Ну вот и не получилость.
$text = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9]/","", mb_strtolower($text, 'UTF-8'));

Comment: @Andrii [смотреть пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/46e3c930d1cd119ef6a60f55da760ed2b3ad1985) (_для просмотра результата нажать кнопку "Execute code"_)

Comment: Что значит вот это строчка?   ('||u')